# How to convert a string datatype column with more than 185 unique values in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, one-hot-encoding

I have a pandas dataframe that consists of more than 17 columns and in that one particular column named Countries which contains more than 180 unique values in the column. How can I perform one-hot encoding in a column with more than 180 columns?

Providing a sample of the entire dataframe

```
Region                              Country
0   Sub-Saharan Africa              Cote d'Ivoire
1   Sub-Saharan Africa              Ethiopia
2   Central America and Caribbean   Panama
3   Europe                          Sweden
4   Europe                          Romania
5   Asia                            Maldives
6   Sub-Saharan Africa              Tanzania
7   Australia                       Tonga
8   Middle East                     Pakistan
9   Sub-Saharan Africa              Chad
10  Central America                 Costa Rica
11  Sub-Saharan Africa              Malawi
12  Asia                            Kyrgyzstan
13  Asia                            Maldives
14  Australia                       Fiji
15  Middle East                     Lebanon
16  Australia                       East Timor
17  Central America                 Guatemala
18  Europe                          Denmark
19  Europe                          Andorra
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas has [get_dummies](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) method to perform one-hot encoding.

```py
pd.get_dummies(df['Country'])
```

Comment: No , If we perform in such a way we would get more than 180 columns .

Comment: @Selva that's exactly what one-hot encoding means. If you just need to encode countries somehow, you can try factorization or entity embeddings.
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html
https://medium.com/@davidheffernan_99410/an-introduction-to-using-categorical-embeddings-ee686ed7e7f9